# javascript to change image source when hover over button

Tags: javascript, image, button, src, onmouseover

Javascript noob here. I've looked for related questions but all the results won't work for me or I don't really understand parts of them. So I might just have done a silly mistake here.

What I'm trying to do is a script that when I hover over a button, changes the source of an image.

HTML:

```
<button onmouseover="changeImg()" class="about" href="#">ABOUT</button>
 <img class="image2" src="images/image2.png">
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function changeImg()
{ 
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("image2");
image.src = "images/image1.png"
}
</script>
```

Is there maybe an easier way to do it? I prefer using only html css and javascript.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might have noticed the `s` in `getElementsByClassName`. It returns multiple element`s`. You can either get the first one by adding `[0]` (`getElementsByClassName('...')[0]`), or use an `id` instead of a `class` if it is supposed to be unique. In which case you can just do `getElementById('...')`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But I tried it out, and it still won't work for me. Am I missing something else...

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `getElementsByClassName` which will return an array of all the elements with that class. Either use `document.getElementByClassName` or `document.querySelector(“element”)`

```
function changeImg() { 
    var image = document.getElementByClassName("image2");
    image.src = "images/image1.png"
}
```

Another solution is to use an event listener with the `e` variable:

```
document.querySelector(“.about”).addEventListener(“mouseover”, function (e) {
    e.target.src = “newSource”
})
```

The `e.target` is the image element

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both, still won't work for me, I'm afraid I'm missing something else...

Comment: are you sure your src goes to the right place

Comment: Pretty sure. But I've found a completely different alternative now. Still thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you end up going with

Comment: Well, I just changed the design of it, essentially it was planned with these images on the button that change color (same image other color)  when you hover over the button. Now what changes when you hover over the button now is the button's background color. Still looks awesome! ;)